# Why the OnMouseDown() event on Rigidbody does not fire?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mouseevent, mouse, rigid-bodies

There is a dynamic Rigidbody that can be launched with the mouse. But at some point, Rigidbody stops reacting to the mouse for some reason. Rigidbody's speed is 0.

To a rigidbody attached two Spring joints.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The only way to awaken the body is to disable and re-enable Spring Joints when debugging.

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{

private Rigidbody2D rigidbodyBall;
public SpringJoint2D[] springJoints;

private GameObject speed;

public static Ball instance = null;

#region Life Cycle

void Awake()
{
    speed = GameObject.Find("Velocity");
    springJoints = GetComponents<SpringJoint2D>();
    rigidbodyBall = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
}

private bool clickedOn = false;
void Update()
{
    if (clickedOn)
    {
        Dragging();
        UIManager.instance.pauseButton.SetActive(false);
        UIManager.instance.totalScoreUI.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        UIManager.instance.pauseButton.SetActive(true);
        UIManager.instance.totalScoreUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}

#endregion

#region Launcher

#region Mouse

void OnMouseDown()
{
   SpringJointDeactivate();
   clickedOn = true;
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    SpringJointActivate();
    clickedOn = false;
    SetKinematicState(false);
    Invoke("SpringJointDeactivate", 0.1f);
}

void Dragging()
{
    Vector3 mouseWorldPointStart = transform.position;
    Vector3 mouseWorldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    mouseWorldPoint.z = 0f;

    if (Boundary.ballInBoundary)
    {
        transform.position = mouseWorldPoint;

        float diffX = mouseWorldPoint.x - mouseWorldPointStart.x;
        //TODO
        for (int i = 0; i < springJoints.Length; i++)
        {
            springJoints[i].connectedAnchor = new Vector2(springJoints[i].connectedAnchor.x + diffX, springJoints[i].connectedAnchor.y);
        }
    }
    else
    {
      Debug.Log("Another situation!");
      Debug.Log(Boundary.ballInBoundary);
    }

}


#endregion

public void SpringJointActivate()
{
    foreach (SpringJoint2D joint in springJoints)
    {
        joint.enabled = true;
    }
}
public void SpringJointDeactivate()
{
    foreach (SpringJoint2D joint in springJoints)
    {
        joint.enabled = false;
    }
}
public Vector3[] GetSpringJointsConnectedAnchorCoord()
{
    Vector3[] springJointsCoord = new[] { Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero };

    for (int i = 0; i < springJoints.Length; i++)
    {
        springJointsCoord[i] = springJoints[i].connectedAnchor;
    }

    return springJointsCoord;
}

#endregion

public void SetKinematicState(bool kinematicState)
{
    rigidbodyBall.isKinematic = kinematicState;
}
```

}

What is the reason for this? How can this be corrected?

Comment: `This function is called on Colliders marked as Trigger if and only if Physics.queriesHitTriggers is true.` is this the case? I don't see any collider in the Inspector so just guess they are there?

Comment: @derHugo, there's a Collider. Added a screenshot.

Comment: So wait, in general how do you confirm that `OnMouseDown` is not called? Did you debug? Maybe add a debug.log to be sure. Or is the issue probably rather in your disabling and enabling joints logic and not really related to `OnMouseDown` itself?

Comment: E.g. where do you call `SetKinematicState(true)`? And why do you activate the joint for 0.1 seconds and then deactivate it again? It's just a bit confusing for me

Comment: In the beginning, everything's fine. OnMouseDown is called. But after about two or three launches, it "freezes". 

I was doing the debugging. I see that the event does not work. Spring joints is part of the mechanism. I don't think they're the reason. Otherwise, it wouldn't have worked right away.

With SetKinematicState(true) I wanted to solve the problem. But this doesn't seem to help.

"And why do you activate the joint for 0.1 seconds and then deactivate it again?"

If this is not done, the mechanism will not work and the ball will just slowly fall down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replaced OnMouseDown() with Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) and everything worked out.

```
void Update()
{
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    SpringJointDeactivate();
    clickedOn = true;
}

if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    SpringJointActivate();
    clickedOn = false;
    SetKinematicState(false);
    Invoke("SpringJointDeactivate", 0.1f);
}
}
```